# Android Limit on the Number of Assets?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is There a limit on the number of assets in android.  I did a google search and found no results.  I know there is a size restriction on files.  However, is there a limit on the number of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your assets are packaged into an APK, you are limited by the max-size allowed by Android Market which is 25 MB (earlier this year). Not 100% sure now.

Without the restriction from Android Market, Android is just like Linux. 2GB file-size limit for Linux and also limit by the maximum available file-handle.